# aspectj not intercepting constructors where class is annotated

Tags: java, aspectj

I would like to intercept all constructor invocations where the class is annotated with a specific annotation.

I have an aspect like this:

```
@Aspect
public class ConstructorClassLevelAspect {
  @Before(
      "execution(*.new(..)) && @annotation(ConstructorClassLevel)")
    public void doConstructorClassLevel(
      JoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("constructed" + point);
  }
}
```

And an instance:

```
@ConstructorClassLevel
public class ConstructorClassLevelExample {

}
```

Now, if I change the aspect and remove the @annotation filter, then I see aspectj is intercepting the call.  Additionally, if I create a default constructor, then annotate it with the annotation, it also works.

But, I want the annotation to live on the class so that if I have 1 constructor or 10, they'll all be intercepted the same (and I only have to put it on the class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if I do @within(ConstructorClassLevelExample), it works!

Comment: Yes, and the reason is that with `@annotation()` you check for an annotation on the joinpoint (here the executed method), with `@within()` you check for an annotation on the type/class containing that joinpoint. P.S.: You can accept your own answer and thus close the question.